# convert tsp distance in eucledian space to real distance (Meter or Kilometer)

Tags: python, distance, traveling-salesman

I am using neural network algorithm to search optimal tour in multiple locations in longitude and latitude. I am using 2D Euclidean space.

Output for result of tsp distance

[image]

How to convert this TSP distance to real distance like meter or kilometer in python?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Maybe you want to get the formula to calculate the distance between two points in (long,lat) format and do all the algorithm in meters. But computing the distance between these points by using Pythagoras and then trying to convert the resulting number to a distance will not work.

Comment: And please, do not post images of text, copy-paste the relevant text into your question.

Comment: No, i am already get solution to calculate. But, the results is using tsp distance unit. The distance not in kilometer or meter. I am confused how to get the real distance @rodrigo

Comment: What is a tsp distance unit?

Comment: Use eucledian distance 2D @rodrigo

Comment: @rodrigo: tsp == Traveling Salesman Problem (although that still doesn't explain much)

Comment: See question [**_Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula). Also see [info about Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using the euclidean distance (ie. Pythagoras theorem) using as X and Y the latitude and longitude directly. That is wrong: lat. and long. measure angles, not distances so to compute those distances you cannot use Pythagoras, you need a different formula (see martineau comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **haversine** distance, see [the Haversine formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). That still presumes your vehicles can fly *as the crow flies*.

---

I've done a number of experiments to compare the impact of using eucledian distance, real road distances and real road times, using [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/learn/useCases/vehicleRoutingProblem.html) on the Vehicle Routing Problem with [the Belgium datasets](http://www.vrp-rep.org/datasets/download/geoffrey-de-smet-2017-belgium-road-km-road-time-air.zip). It matters for about 4%.

[image]

PS: To search optimal tour in multiple locations, use **Local Search**, not Neural Nets (and visa versa for image recognition). Use the right tool for the job. See academic challenges for proof.